# create a json array from html table

Tags: javascript, json

i have C++ program exporting log files as HTML table and I wanted to know if there is any way that i can parse that table(something like this):

```
<table>
<tr><td>id</td><td>value1</td><td>value2</td></tr>
<tr><td>0 </td><td>0     </td><td>0     </td></tr>
<tr><td>0 </td><td>1.5   </td><td>2.15  </td></tr>
</table>
```

into a JSON array (something like this) using a Javascript function:

```
 var chartData = [
            {id:"0",value1:"0",value2:"0"},
            {id:"1",value1:"1.5",value2:"2.15"}];
```

The problem is that I want this function to work for every table given to it, with any possible row or column count(first row is always a header).

Comment: `chartData` is a normal JavaScript array, not JSON (something must be wrong today, so many people confusing this).

Comment: anyway how can i extract data from table to array?

Comment: If you can use jquery, this should be an easy job.

Comment: Interesting challenge to do without jQuery though...  accepted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my implementation:

```
var tableToObj = function( table ) {
    var trs = table.rows,
        trl = trs.length,
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        keys = [],
        obj, ret = [];

    for (; i < trl; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            for (; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
                keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
            }
        } else {
            obj = {};
            for (j = 0; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
                obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
            }
            ret.push(obj);
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

Which you would invoke like:

```
var obj = tableToObj( document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0] ); // or
var obj = tableToObj( document.getElementById('myTable') );
```

[**See working example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/dGPks/)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, assuming the first row is always the header (could certainly be changed to make it more flexible):

```
function getData(table, format) {
    var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows,
        header_row = rows[0],
        result = [],
        header = [],
        format = format || function(val){return val;},
        i, j, cell, row, row_data;

    // extract header
    for(i = 0, l = header_row.cells.length; i < l; i++) {
        cell = header_row.cells[i];
        header.push((cell.textContent || cell.innerText));
    }

    // extract values
    for(i = 1, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
        row = rows[i];
        row_data = {};
        for(j = 0, l = row.cells.length; j < l; j++) {
            cell = row.cells[j];
            row_data[header[j]] = format(i, j, cell.textContent || cell.innerText);
        }
        result.push(row_data);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage is:

```
var chartData = getData(referenceToTable, function(rowIndex, colIndex, value) {
    return +value; // shortcut to format text to a number
});
```

By passing a format function, you can format the values of each cell into the right data type.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/EHW5q/)

It works under the assumption that there is only one `tbody` element. You have to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I had to change this line : "row_data[header[j]] = format(i, j, cell.textContent || cell.innerText)" to : "row_data[header[j]] = format(cell.textContent || cell.innerText)" to make it work.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe: How many parameters does your format function accept? It must be three if you wanted to use the code as is.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the jquery framework. I

```
<sript src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  var chartData = [];
  $("table tr").each(function(i){
    if(i==0) return;
    var id = $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).html());
    var value1 = $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(1).html());
    var value2 = $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(2).html());
    chartData.push({id: id, value1: value1, value2: value2});
  });
//now you have the chartData array filled
});
</script>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing except with the ability to ignore columns, override values, and not be confused by nested tables. I ended up writing a jQuery plugin `table-to-json`:

https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json

All you have to do is select your table using jQuery and call the plugin:

```
var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
```

Here is a demo of it in action using your data:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGPks/199/

Answer (score 0):

Since that table format looks like well-formed XML, I'd use XSLT to make the conversion; your C++ program could then just invoke an XSLT engine.