# Parse html table data to JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am scraping a webpage and need to return data from a  `<table>` in JSON format.
There's an enclosing `<table class="grid_table">` that nests multiple `<table class="mydetails">` (In the code below I only pasted 2).
From these nested tables I want to return a JSON array with the cell data. There's always 4 cells with different class Names. The first is a datestring and the other three are strings within a `<div>`. Below I put my desired output in JSON.
I am not familiar with javascript, so this is all I have come up with until now:

```
var t = document.querySelectorAll('table.mydetails');
t.forEach(function(table) {
    datas = table.querySelectorAll("td");
    datas.forEach(function(cell) {
        
        var divs = cell.querySelectorAll('div');
        
        divs.forEach(function(div) {
            console.log(div.textContent);
        });
    });
});
```

I am sure there's better ways to do this and I would appreciate if someone could give me a little help here.

This is my webpage:

```
<html>
<table class="grid_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="grid_row_1 grid_row_pr_2021-11-01" role="row">
            <td role="gridcell">
                <div class="classCell">
                    <div class="classMultiLine">
                        <table class="mydetails">
                            <tr class="">
                                <td class="td-e">01.11.2021</td>
                                <td class="td-d Target">
                                    <div class="">Foo1</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="td-d Mine">
                                    <div class="">Bar1</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="td-d His">
                                    <div class="">FooBar1</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="classMultiLine">empty</div>
                    <div class="classMultiLine">empty</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="grid_row_2 grid_row_pr_2021-11-02" role="row">
            <td role="gridcell">
                <div class="classCell">
                    <div class="classMultiLine">
                        <table class="mydetails">
                            <tr class="">
                                <td class="td-e">02.11.2021</td>
                                <td class="td-d Target">
                                    <div class="">Foo2</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="td-d Mine">
                                    <div class="">Bar2</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="td-d Hi">
                                    <div class="">FooBar2</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="classMultiLine">empty</div>
                    <div class="classMultiLine">empty</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

This is my desired output:

```
[
  {
    "date": "01.11.2021",
    "Target": "Foo1",
    "Mine": "Bar1",
    "His": "FooBar1"
  },
  {
    "date": "02.11.2021",
    "Target": "Foo2",
    "Mine": "Bar2",
    "His": "FooBar2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here can be used `array.prototype` method to create arrays, and to create objects for each mydetails table I used object `constructor`. `Map` method creates a new array, `forEach` method - doesn't. At the end of the code, you can find 2 results (in `JSON` or in js format).

```
let list = (t) => {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(t);
    }

    function Table(date,target,mine,his){
        this.date = date;
        this.target = target;
        this.mine = mine;
        this.his = his;
    }

    const t = document.querySelectorAll('table.mydetails');
    const dataArr = list(t);
    const separate = dataArr.map((el)=>{
        const obj = el.querySelectorAll('td');
        return list(obj);
    });
    const finalArray = separate.map(element => {
        const text = list(element).map(el => {
            return el.innerText;
        });
        return text;
    });


    const result = finalArray.map(el=>{
        const final = new Table(el[0],el[1],el[2],el[3]);
        return final;
    });
console.log(result)
    const resultFinal = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log('Scrapped results', resultFinal);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! It works as intended. Just a quick question: If I did not want `Table` objects to be added to the `finalArray` where `el[1]` is `"0:00"`, how would I do that? I added  a `if(el[1] != "0:00"`before `return final;` but then I end up with `null` elements in the `resultFinal`.

Comment: Add additional filter.  `const result = finalArray.map(el=>{
    const final = new Table(el[0],el[1],el[2],el[3]);
    if(el[1] !== '0:00'){
        return final;
    }
});
const checkNull = (el) => {
    return el !== undefined;
}
const filteredResult = result.filter(checkNull);
const resultFinal = JSON.stringify(filteredResult);
console.log('Scrapped results', resultFinal);`

Answer (score 1):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917763/12489824). It has included code with DEMO working. Just change in that demo the last line at the bottom from `console.dir(chartData);` to `console.log(chartData);` to see results in Console.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following JS code.

```
var t = document.querySelectorAll('table.mydetails');
var mainArray= [];
t.forEach(function(table) {
debugger;
    datas = table.querySelectorAll("td");
    var dateCell=datas[0].innerText;
    var targetCell=datas[1].children[0].innerText;
    var mineCell=datas[2].children[0].innerText;
    var hisCell=datas[3].children[0].innerText;
    
    var currentObject = {"date":dateCell, "Target":targetCell, "Mine":mineCell, "His":hisCell};
    mainArray.push(currentObject);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(mainArray));
```